# Activiti - End the name of the End Event in which Process Instance Ended

Tags: spring, activiti

I want to get the name of the end event in which my process instance ended. I am using Activiti version 7 (spring boot starter of activit). Could anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also had similar question, and I know this is bit old now, but still ...

You can use HistoryService to get finished process ( presuming you have some id of it )

```
@Autowired
private HistoryService historyService;
```

Please consider my code sniplet, which will actually end process due to end of path

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>(); // Some params

Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery()
        .processInstanceId(processId)
        .singleResult();

taskService.complete(task.getId(), params); //params optional, this ends whole process 

List<HistoricVariableInstance> allVars = historyService
        .createHistoricVariableInstanceQuery()
        .processInstanceId(navTask.getProcessId())
        .list();
//return to user all filled in forms etc.

HistoricProcessInstance historicProcess = historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(navTask.getProcessId()).singleResult();
String endId = historicProcess.getEndActivityId(); //This returns ID where your process ended
```

If id of ending activity is not enough you can go with more digging:

```
String procDefId = historicProcess.getProcessDefinitionId()
FlowElement  flowEl = repositoryService.getBpmnModel(procDefId).getMainProcess().getFlowElements()
       .stream()
       .filter(flowElement -> flowElement.getId().equals("endId"))
       .findFirst()
       .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new)
flowEl.getName() //your name and other stuff you need
```

One bottom note: In my case history was not persisted  and had to update application  properties with `spring.activiti.historyLevel=activity` and `spring.activiti.dbHistoryUsed=true`